# Double.parseDouble throwing numberFormatException

Tags: format, double, processing

I'm trying to convert a string into a double in processing using this code

```
double distanceTravelled = Double.parseDouble(InfoList.get(i).tripDistance);
```

however it throws a numberFormatException: For input string "trip_distance"

I don't know why it's throwing an exception as it should just convert the string to a double
Anyone know why it's throwing this exception?
Thank you

Comment: What's the value of the string? Two options: or tripDistance is not a number or is in a different Locale.

Comment: Print out the value of tripDistance right before you pass it into the parseDouble() function. Chances are it's not a numeric String: in fact, it looks like it's the String "trip_distance", which obviously is not something you can parse. If you want better help, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that passes a hard-coded value into the parseDouble() function.